# Install Flutter in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I have installed Flutter in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I've even updated the path in the .bashrc file as shown below

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/fredriq/flutter_dev/flutter/flutter/bin"
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

But when I type flutter in the terminal I get this output:

```
flutter: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the path from the terminal is temporary.
Open .bashrc using Gedit and add it in manually.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Then at the very bottom, add this line:

```
export PATH="$HOME/flutter_dev/flutter/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

Finally source .bashrc or close and reopen any open terminals

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: this is exactly what i did

Comment: A quick fix, my example : `cd /usr/local/bin/ && sudo ln -s /home/knudfl/tmp2/flutter/bin/flutter` .... and the 'flutter' command is OK.

Comment: Thank you so much, cd /usr/local/bin/ && sudo ln -s /home/knudfl/tmp2/flutter/bin/flutter worked

Answer (score 1):

You can install flutter by snap. Open Terminal and execute below command.

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

Answer (score 1):

The Flutter SDK snap package provides everything needed to develop Flutter apps on Ubuntu. There's no need to install a bunch of development dependencies. Simply install the Flutter SDK snap package and your favorite IDE and you're ready to start developing with Flutter.

To install Flutter SDK in Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

You may also be interested in these two other Flutter snap packages.

- flutter-gallery - a gallery of widgets and behaviors, plus demos and vignettes, all built with Flutter.
- flutter-ui-challenges - awesome Flutter UIs for real world applications with codes, free to use in your next flutter application.

If your code editor of choice is Visual Studio Code, run the following commands:

```
snap install code --classic  
code --install-extension dart-code.flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I propose you to run this command

   ```
   echo 'export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
   echo 'export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Check that the new path is indeed into the ~/.bashrc

   ```
   tail ~/.bashrc
   ```

Finally source .bashrc or close and reopen any open terminals

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Feel free to follow this tutorial : https://medium.com/@Abdelkrim/install-flutter-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa-65ca0f86e02e

Comment: okay but it already worked using knud larsen method but I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Install flutter by clicking on [the link](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.0.6-stable.tar.xz).

Run following commands then

```
cd ~/development
tar xf ~/Downloads/flutter_linux_2.0.6-stable.tar.xz
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

You directly install from [snapd](https://snapcraft.io/).

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Flutter on Linux is by using snapd.

1. open the terminal
2. Copy-paste the command line **

> $ sudo snap install flutter --classic

**

1. Once the snap is installed, you can use the following command to display your Flutter SDK path **

> $ flutter sdk-path

**